# How to join different tables based on 'if else' conditions

Tags: sql, if-statement, join

I want to join candidate table with symbols table if status of candidate is 'independent' and with party table if status of candidate is'party'

Is there any way in sql to execute a query like this or if you can suggest any other solution.

```
Example:
Select * from candidate c 
if c.status='party' 
JOIN party p on p.party_id = c.party_id
else if c.status='independent'
JOIN symbol s on s.symbol_id = c.symbol_id
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` in the `from` and then `coalesce()` in the `select`:

```
Select c.*, coalesce(c.col1, s.col1) as col1, . . .
from candidate c left join
     party p  
     on p.party_id = c.party_id and c.status = 'party' left join
     symbol s
     on s.symbol_id = c.symbol_id and c.status = 'independent';
```

The `coalesce()` chooses the values for columns from the matching table (only one can match because of the condition on `c.status`).